# Use a lookup table to fill nans in another table pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
col_a | col_b |
===============
101   | abc   |
102   | def   |
103   | NaN   |
104   | pqr   |
105   | NaN   |
```

I want to fill these NaN values with the correct value using a corresponding lookup table `lookup_df` that looks like this:

```
val_a | val_b |
===============
101   | abc   |
102   | def   |
103   | ghi   |
104   | pqr   |
105   | stu   |
```

I know that I can do a left merge, but since it is possible to have the same value in `col_a`, I want to essentially just fill all NANs by looking at `lookup_df`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
s = lookup_df.set_index('val_a')['val_b']

df1['col_b'] = df1['col_b'].fillna(df1['col_b'].map(s))
```

**Explanation**

- Create a mapping from `val_a` to `val_b`.
- Use this mapping to `fillna` entries in `col_b`.
- This works because `pd.Series.map` accepts a series as an input.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if all values in col_a is found in val_a. If not, let me know and will find another solution. Thanks.

```
df1['col_b'] = df1['col_a'] \
               .apply(lambda col_a: lookup_df['val_b'][lookup_df['val_a'] == col_a] \
               .values[0]) 
print(df1)
      Input:
         col_a col_b
    0    101   abc
    1    102   def
    2    103   NaN

  Sample result:
     col_a col_b
    0    101   abc
    1    102   def
    2    103   cat
```

Comment: All values in col_a are not always found in val_a (however, each value in val_a is unique). Also, there can be duplicate values within col_a.